# How we can check NAPI feature is enabled or not in linux?

Tags: linux

I want to check NAPI feature is enabled in our linux or not. we are using bnx2 driver.

Our linux os is RHEL5 and kernel is 2.6.18-164.el5PAE

If anyone knows please help.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just generate continuous network traffic to the network interface using a traffic generator. Make sure **not to* generate back traffic through the interface. Then do:

watch cat /proc/interrupts | grep bnx2

You will see the interrupt line statistics that the bnx2 driver has registered on.

Does the interrupt count keep rising in relation to the packet rate? then NAPI is off. Is the interrupt count steady or rises much slowly then the packet rate? NAPI is on.

Note that a shared interrupt line with some other device/driver may complicate the test.

Comment: Hi gby,I tried with this command cat /proc/interrupts | grep bnx2 but its not giving any statistics

Comment: @Hanish I assumed the bnx2 driver registers "bnx2" as its name when registering for the interrupt. It seems that it isn't - so simply do cat /proc/interrupts and look for the name the bnx2 registers the interrupt with and repeat the procedure with the name you've found.

Comment: Hi gby, Thanks for ur reply... I tested in my pc NAPI is not enabled Please tell me, how we can enable the NAPI feature.

Comment: No idea. Sorry. From a look at the driver it looks like it will use NAPI if compiled for it, so my guess is - you need to rebuild the driver from source with the right config option